# Load youtube URL in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have been looking at numerous tutorials to play youtube videos via the app. However they are producing a blank screen. According to comments on the tutorials this is common on xocde 5? Is there another way in which videos can be streamed? I am running it on a iphone and have connected the webview.

I am using :

**.h**

```
@interface detailViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
```

**VIEW DID LOAD**

```
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/AmMF7hWrYZk\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Comment: Try loadRequest in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you wired up webView to your storyboard?

Comment: I can load the webview when using a standard url such as www.google.co.uk but I wish to embed the youtube link in so it streams the video and this is failing to load. I have updated the link above to show you. It is just a blank page. @Ethan yeah I am not that new ;)

Comment: Ohh, okay. But you specify the url as an html string. Maybe you want to call "[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];" instead?

Comment: @ethan - hah , nice spot.

Comment: @ethan out of interest how would i make that work?

Comment: @ethan I actual ended up using ur suggestion but you never put it in a answer

Comment: It is a minor problem which you would have found it pretty soon too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented youtube videos using the [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser). Very nice and easy to use.

Comment: **Warning: This is not approved by the ToC of YouTube. Use at own risk.** Than why you suggest this to use.?

Comment: I used this and its working fine from the past two years. I have no issues with this. Rest is upon you whether you want to use or not. Another solutions to write your own parser for youtube url.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIWebView *web;
NSString *pageHTML = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"url" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pageHTML   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[web loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

the code in url.html is

> ```
> <html>
>    <head></head>
> <body>
>     <iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/73198189?title=1&byline=0&portrait=0&loop=1' width='690' height='500' frameborder='10' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>myframe</iframe>
> </body>
> ```

i have used this code for playing vimeo videos and it worked.. hope this helps you..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue happen when I was using the YouTubeHelper Xcode libraries (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).  I found that the first time I added the YT* libraries into my project that I didn't select the "Create Folder References for any added folders" when adding the assets folder into my Xcode project.  After removing the existing assets folder and following that step I was able to get the helper libraries to work within my project and play YouTube videos as the link above describes.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider letting the web view tell you why its not loading

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your view controller , and attach the delegate to your view  controller.

`- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`

may give you a very good hint.

Answer (score 0):

Send you `NSURLRequest` request from

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}
```

Here is my code, used in my app

```
NSString *youTubeID = [self extractYoutubeID:url];
 NSString *embedHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                          <html><head>\
                          <style type=\"text/css\">\
                          body {\
                          background-color: #666666;\
                          padding:%f %f %f %f;\
                          color: blue;\
                          }\
                          </style>\
                          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <iframe height=\"%f\" width=\"%f\" title=\"YouTube Video\" class=\"youtube-player\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" ></iframe>\
                          </body></html>",paddingTop,paddingRight,paddingBottom,paddingLeft,videoHeight,videoWidth,youTubeID];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];



// extractYoutubeID
+ (NSString *)extractYoutubeID:(NSString *)youtubeURL
{
    //NSLog(@"youtube  %@",youtubeURL);
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSString *regexString = @"(?<=v(=|/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(?<=youtu.be/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:youtubeURL options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [youtubeURL length])];
    if(!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)))
    {
        NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [youtubeURL substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
        return substringForFirstMatch;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You forgot to put "http://" in your youtube link.

Here's the correct code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/AmMF7hWrYZk\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```